# C - Shift Array Over

Tags: c, arrays

I've been attempting to take a character array with some indices having characters and some having null characters and change it to only an array with characters - shifting over indices to remove the null spaces when need be.

This is my approach so far:

```
char *args[256];
void removeNulls(){
    for(int i=0; i<=token; i++){
        if(args[i] == '\0'){
            shiftleft(i);
        }
       }
}

void shiftleft(int start){
    for(int i=start; i<token; i++){
            *(args+i) = *(args + i +1);
                }
}
```

However, when I do this and print out the result I notice that in the args array,
that is the initial args array, it consists of : null, null, 1,2,3,4 after removing nulls this array becomes null,1,2,3,4 instead of the desired 1,2,3,4. Is there something I'm missing in my loop conditions to account for this?

Comment: Could you show your complete program? That does not compile.

Comment: BTW, there's a convenient shorthand for `*(args+i)`: it can be (and usually is) written as `args[i]`.

Answer (score 4):

One index gets skipped every time you hit a null, because you always increment `i` even when you are skipping. You should increment `i` only when not skipping, for example like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<=token; ) {
    if (args[i] == '\0') {
        shiftleft(i);
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}
```

By the way, the algorithm is not optimal when there are multiple nulls, because for every null, you shift the entire remaining part. It is possible to shift the contents over the nulls in a single pass, by tracking the current index and the next index to fill. For each null value, the next fill index will get one step behind the current index.

```
for (int i=0, next = 0; i<=token; i++) {
    if (args[i] != '\0') {
        args[next++] = args[i];
    }
}
```

Last thing, what about the excess elements? That is, for the input null, null, 1, 2, 3, token, the resulting content will be 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, token. Is that OK like that? I suggest to check your requirement, as maybe you have some tasks concerning these remaining elements. I leave that for your exercise.

Answer (score 0):

When i=0, when shiftleft(0) is called,

Whatever value is at address pointed by (args+i)->(args+0)->"null" is replaced with (args+i+1)->(args+0+1)->"null".

This is why your output prints null,1,2,3,4.

Change your input to null,1,2,3,4 and you will see the difference.The output will then be 1,2,3,4